# How to deal with demanding fees to accept the article

Tags: publications, peer-review, ethics

An author submitted a manuscript to a Scopus and a Web of Science Journal. Few months later, he received an email including the full name of the author, name of Journal and the title of the submitted manuscript. The email asking the author to pay $$ in order to accept reviewing the paper. Then, accept it for publication. The author immediately block the sender and report it as a spam. Then attached the spam email and send the case to the Journal asking for investigation. Should the author do any further action?

The sender was not associated with the journal. But how he got the information of the author? The sender ask for money to accept reviewing the paper and guarantee acceptance the paper. Hence, whatever the paper is, paying the money will result in accepting the manuscript.

The story in points:

1- Authour submitted the manuscript.

2- The status of the manuscript becomes "Reviwer invited" after about a month.

3- After 2 months the Author received unethic email. The email asked about the following:

● Gurantee accepting the paper for publication with one condition. The condition is to pay 200$ to the sender.

● before paying, the author must respond the sender with accepting the deal.

● Then, the sender accept the invitation to review the manuscript. Once this is apear in the system "Under review". Then, the authour pay the 200$.

● In 10 days, the paper will be accepted.

The journal is an open access journal. The author send the unethic email to the Journal asking for the investigation.  It is Ok to reject the paper for 100 times, but it is not ok to published it in an unethical way. This is completely unacceptable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Was the sender associated with the journal? Open Access journals are normally supported by author fees. Some other journals partially so. There isn't enough information here to suggest anything other than you may have a misunderstanding.

Comment: > *Should the author do any further action?* -- It depends on the intent. What are you trying to achieve? Most people would likely agree that the sender's actions are unethical and do not align well with academic values. But not all academics agree on how much effort one should commit to protect those academic values, when it does not concern them directly. Some would delete email and do nothing else, some would contact sender's department and even police. This is largely a personal choice, and as such, your question may be considered off-topic here.

Comment: Sounds like someone (i.e. the journal) suffered a data breach and the scammers are trying to take advantage.

Comment: You appear to use "author" to describe different parties in this situation; can you please revise to clarify who is who.

Comment: @Buffy the sender seems not associated with the journal. However, instead of investigating in this case, the journal reject my paper. The last status was "Reviwer invited" then suddenly it becomes rejected??!! So this make me  feel that the journal is behind the unethic email.

Comment: @Buffy No there were no misunderstanding. The sender ask to pay 200$ to accept reviewing the manuscript. The payment must be done after accepting reviewing the manuscript. So, the authour (me) must first agree on this deal. Then, the reviwer accept reviewing. Then, the author pay, then the paper accepted. This is the story. So, it seems the journal involved.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the e-mail purported to be from an individual referee soliciting a personal bribe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you think this journal is *really* demanding fees from you to accept the article. That's extremely unlikely (note the journal is indexed by Scopus & Web of Science). Far more likely that someone is impersonating the journal and trying to scam authors. In other words, if you had actually paid the "journal", your paper would still be rejected.

The odds are good your paper is rejected because it is not "good enough". This especially applies if the journal sent you reviewer reports that clearly say your paper is not good enough.

> Should the author do any further action?

No, for the simple reason: what further action *can* the author take? What can the authors possibly imagine doing that will actually have an impact, beyond what they have already been done? I suppose they could file a police report, but it's the journal being impersonated, so the journal is the aggrieved party and they are the ones with [standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_(law)). If they don't do anything then nobody else can.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. 

Answer (score 2):

You did the only thing that you could do: Involve the editor. It seems at first glance that the reviewer selected by the journal decided to get paid for their work of reviewing and then extended this by selling a positive review for a little money.

It could be that local laws were broken (maybe some type of fraud or bribery), so you *possibly* could bring this to the attention of the authorities.

If the reviewer is affiliated with an academic institution, you could (and should) inform their authorities since soliciting bribes for positive reviews is very unethical. You might have to leave this to the editor since they know more about what has happened and the identity of the reviewer.

Of course, you might be dealing with a predatory editor, in which case the reviewer might have decided to profit just as well.